# Dlg shows twice using the getOpenFileName() in PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

A Gui(only a edit box and a button) is created in Qt Designer, when clicking the button, a window shows, and the selected file'path appears in the edit box. But when I clicked the button, two windows are opened, the slot is coded as follow:

```
def on_openBtn_clicked(self):
    fileName = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
        self,'choose the file',options = QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog)
    self.fileRoadEdt.setText(fileName)
```

then I edit the code like:

```
def on_openBtn_clicked(self):
    dialog = QFileDialog(self)
    dialog.exec_()
    for fileName in dialog.selectedFiles():
        self.fileRoadEdt.setText(fileName)
```

the same thing happen, what mistake am I making?

Comment: The code looks ok. Are you sure you're not getting the signal twice, for some reason? (Easy to test: just print some message a the beginning of the slot)

Comment: now I'm trying to re-install the python(xy), another trouble arises. It can't be re-installed correctly.\n  Error creating: D:\Program Files (x86)\pythonxy\Uninstall.exe
Completed

Comment: maybe you've connected it twice in your code